# Refresh from server and only update new elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, angularjs

I'm refreshing data from the server every several seconds.  Everything works pretty well, but for a moment the data will be doubled while the previous data is being displayed by Angular and the next data is being added in.  This is especially obvious with ng-animate since every element is animated out and then in again.

```
app.factory("models", function ($http) {
    return {
        models: [],
        fetchModels: function () {
            var models = this;
            $http.get("/models").success(function (serverModels) {
                models.models = serverModels;
            }); 
        });
    };
});
```

I think that part of the problems stems from overwriting the entire array.  Is there a simple way (or any way for that matter) in Angular to only push new `serverModels` elements onto the array so that existing elements don't have to be rewritten?

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with overwriting your models on scope, and likely an issue with your CSS transitions on ng-leave and ng-leave-active classes.  Here is a plunker that illustrates how it should work. http://plnkr.co/edit/c2QDSkih7Wg93RemHG4g?p=preview

Comment: @pixelbits remove the `++index` line and see that everything is still animated again (`test1` over and over).  This is undesirable.

Comment: Can you loop over them and check for duplicates by comparing the identity property, and only push the element if that's not the case?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I see. Assuming you have a unique key for your model, you can use 'track by' in your repeat expression so that angular knows which items are unique and already exists, and which ones are new. The new items - angular will animate. Here is an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/c2QDSkih7Wg93RemHG4g?p=preview

Comment: @mtyson I can, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do that / a more angular way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'track by' in your repeat expression so that Angular knows which items are unique and already exists, and which items are new.

Even though you completely overwrite the array on scope, Angular will know to apply CSS animations to items that are new because of the unique key.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data track by item.id"> {{item.name }}</div>
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c2QDSkih7Wg93RemHG4g?p=preview)